# Configure D-link WIFI WAP as repeater

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, repeater

I have [Dlink DWL - 2000AP+](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/product/dwl-2000applus-802-11g-high-speed-wireless-access-point?revision=deu_reva).

What I want to do is, to reproduce WiFi signal (from TP-LINK modem) by repeating with the help of a D-Link Wireless Access Point.

Here is how web interface looks. There is an option for repeating:

[image]

after clicking <kbd>Site Survey</kbd> I see all list of available networks. When I select one of them, the D-link saves changes then reboots. After that, Windows shows me something like that on available WiFi networks list:

```
<Repeated network name> 2
```

The problem is, when I connect to this network, Windows connects directly into root source, not to my WAP (I see this with [inSSIDer utility](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/)).

I can't figure out what the problem is, or how I can realise my idea.  What am I missing?  Anyone familiar with this type of connection?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [manual](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/product/-/media/Consumer_Products/DWL/DWL%202000AP%20Plus/Manual/DWL%202000AP%20Plus_Manual_EN_UK.pdf) for your device (page 17), this is also refered to as 'Multi-point bridging' and is used to connect multiple wifi network together. it also says that the other networks must be using DWL-2000AP+s, so it cant repeat just any wifi network.